# jquery mobile - how to use the "error reporting dialog"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

when using jquery mobile, and you load an invalid page, an error message is reported elegantly showing loading page failed(then fades out). Check out the attached image.

i want to use this ui to report my own custom error messages and animate them the way its done. any one had any experience doing this?

i would like to report some errors without using dialogs and this method seems appropriate. Can this be done using jquery and if please show the code.[image]

Comment: This question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267159/jquery-mobile-how-to-invoke-this-default-error-loading-page-message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the latest 1.1.0 RC version you can use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg` to display custom error messages:

```
// show error message
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg( $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessageTheme, $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage, true );

// hide after delay
setTimeout( $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg, 1500 );
```

Comment: im using jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js and it fails. just spins and shows loading, lemme look for that version

Comment: With 1.0.1 you need to see the answer JackieChiles posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: Sir Lojik, try to add : $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true; to your project...that will let you show text on the messages

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problem. I needed to show validation errors after validating submited form. So I've wrote this code:

```
function showErrorMessage(message, $container, delay) {
    $err = $('<div/>', {
        id: 'error_message'
    });
    $err.attr('data-role', 'popup');
    $err.attr('data-theme', 'e');
    $err.attr('data-overlay-theme', 'a');
    $err.attr('data-position-to', 'window');
    $err.addClass('ui-content');
    $err.text(message);

    $container.children().detach();
    $container.append($err);

    $err.popup( );
    $err.popup( "open" );

    if(delay > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $err.popup( "close" );
        }, delay);
    }
}
```

It shows this message:
[image]

Comment: how is this function used?

Comment: First of all - you must have jQm imported to your html file. Then if something gone wrong just call
`showErrorMessage("uuups!", $('#error'), 1000);`
and this popup should appear for one second.
I'm not sure if there is something more to do, because I have not seen this project since March

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution could be:

```
function show_error_message(message, delay) {
    $.mobile.loading('show',
                     { theme: "e", text: (message || 'ERROR'),
                       textonly: true, textVisible: true });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }, ((delay && delay > 0) ? delay : 1000));
}
```

Usage:

```
show_error_message("Wow!!!", 1500);
```

The message `Wow!!!` will be shown in the center of window.

Comment: This seems to work for me in jqm 1.4.  The accepted answer didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for hiding the error div:

```
div.ui-loader.ui-overlay-shadow { display: none !important; }
```